# Best syntax to create multi-line string

Tags: c#, .net, string, syntax, multiline

What's the best way to create multi-line string in C#?

I know the following methods:

#### Using StringBuilder

```
var result = new StringBuilder().AppendLine("one").AppenLine("two").ToString()
```

looks too verbose.

#### Using @

```
      var result = @"one
two"
```

looks ugly and badly formatted.

### Do you know better ways?

Comment: If you're really going for "literals only", or just have some basic replacements to make, and have a lot of text (for example, usage messages for console applications come to mind), you could also use a "template" plain-text embedded resource.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What about this:

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new string[]{ 
    "one",
    "two" 
});
```

It's a bit painful and possibly an overkill, but it gives the possibility to preserve the lines separation in your code.
To improve things a little, you could use an helper method:

```
static string MultiLine(params string[] args) {
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, args);
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var result = MultiLine( 
        "one",
        "two" 
    );
}
```

Comment: Not too bad. I think I'll create extension method and use like this:
new[] { "One", "Two" }.Join(Environment.NewLine) or even create a class and use like this: StringHelper.JoinLines("one", "two")

Comment: I had thought about the extension method, but in the end I think I prefer the "plain" old-style utility...

Answer (score 12):

What about this?

```
var result = "one\ntwo";
```

If you're fussy about OS-specific line endings, use `Format`:

```
var result = String.Format("one{0}two", Environment.NewLine);
```

(Well, “fussy” isn’t the right word: when dealing with text files, OS-specific line endings are often desired or even necessary, when dealing with legacy software.)

Comment: Nice but I'd prefer to separate lines with <", "> rather than with <{0}>. One character more but {0} pisses me off a bit.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is a very very open ended point.

Are you after :

- Performance of the code
- Speed the coder can write it
- Ability for another coder to understand it easily
- Ability for another coder to modify it easily

All of those make a big difference as to the "best" way of doing something.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends on what You need...

But to simplify it I would go with:

```
var s = new StringBuilder();
s.Append("one");
s.Append("two");
s.ToString();
```

But since we don't know what You need it for. It's pretty difficult to give better hints

Comment: I did exactly this before. StringBuilder supports fluent interface - see my question why I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should not define large strings in your source code. 
You should define it in an external text file:

```
string s = File.OpenText("myfile.txt").ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off of [what @codymanix said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508191/best-syntax-to-create-multi-line-string/1512224#1512224), you could place the long multiline string in a resource file. This can be easier for certain deployment scenarios since the text "file" will be included in your DLL / EXE.

Comment: +1 - I always do this for relatively big files but it's not very convenient when you need to write many small tests. It also decreases locality of code.

Answer (score 1):

Ehm, how about:

```
string s = 
  "abc\n" + 
  "def\n" ;
```

Comment: You answer is very similar to Konrad Rudolph's. I'd prefer to use Environment.NewLine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need more than one line.
I use Environment.NewLine but I placed it in a method to multiply it. :)

```
    private string newLines(int multiplier)
    {
        StringBuilder newlines = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
            newlines.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        return newlines.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: So how do you create string "one<newline>two"?

Comment: If you need just one line I'd use Konrad's solution because it seems to me the simplest one. However, if you needed more than one line I'd use StringBuilder and Append("one" + NewLines(3) + "two") for instance.